# Chunked transfer-encoding in django rest framework (nginx+gunicorn)

Tags: django, http-headers, icalendar, django-rest-framework, transfer-encoding

I've built an API using Django Rest Framework to serve ical feed from my django models.
The feed content is validated and works in all calendar applications I've tested *except iCal on iOS*. iCal on iOs will accept the content if copy/pasted but won't accept to import from url.

I suspect the cause of this problem is the http-header:
**transfer-encoding: chunked**

I'm trying to figure out why the transfer is chunked, and to see if fixing this will allow iOS to read the feed.

Here are some simplified code:

**Renderer**

```
from rest_framework import renderers

class ICALRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
   media_type = 'text/html'
   format = 'ical'
   charset = 'utf-8'

   def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
      blob = tools.ical_generator(data, 'My calendar name', 'My calendar description')
      return blob
```

**tools.ical_generator**

```
def ical_generator(events=[], calname='', caldesc=''):
    cal = vobject.iCalendar()
    # build header
    # iterate over events 
    # build footer
    icalstream = cal.serialize()
    return icalstream
```

note-1: When doing *wget*, only the *header* and the *footer* from the ical_generator will show and the transfer won't complete but "hang" indefinitely.

note-2: the API is also used for other purposes than ical feed, and in other circumstances the http-header is **not** chunked.

Comment: just a note: iCal/iOS not supporting chunked transfer encoding would be a pretty bad bug, as per rfc2616, 'All HTTP/1.1 applications MUST be able to receive and decode the "chunked" transfer-coding[...]'

Answer (score 0):

Use Content-type: text/calendar and iCal on iOS will eat it.

text/html and text/plain are allowed by all other validation tools i've tested, so seems iOS is very picky...